# Sharepoint API using python: what is the relative path of my folders?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, python

I'm trying to upload files automatically from a python script using the office365.sharepoint package. I can authenticat using a client id and secret (app_principal). However, when I try to get a file list I fail. For example, I'm currently trying to use `web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url`, but no matter what relative path I enter, it fails. So, my question basically is: what path do I have to use as a parameter here? On my sharepoint online site, the site is named for example "Company_A" (top left) and when I go to the documents, the main folder is "Documents", which is not listed in the folder view but it's something like a header. Then the folders are "folder_a/folder_b", etc.

I want to list files in folder_b. As an input for the API call, I used "Company_A/folder_a/folder_b", also "Company_A/Shared Documents/folder_a/folder_b", "Shared Documents/folder_a/folder_b", "Documents/folder_a/folder_b", "Company_A/Documents/folder_a/folder_b", "folder_a/folder_b"... basically everything and I always get either an empty list, or an exception or similar. Can you help me out?

Comment: Try ”/sites/Company_A/Shared Documents/folder_a/folder_b”.

Comment: You might need to encode the URL to, so replace ”/sites/Company_A/Shared%20Documents/folder_a/folder_b” could be it.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. Thanks for the option though.